# CountDownTimer keeps repeating loop

Tags: java, android

I have a timer:

```
new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
            {label.setText("Seconds Remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);}

        public void onFinish() {doSomething();}
     }.start();
```

It counts down from 10, and if it reaches 0 method 'doSomething()' is run. But it keeps repeating itself. I need 'doSomething()' to run only 10 times overall. Baring in mind that if the timer does not reach 0 another method needs to also run.

thanks, for any help

Comment: How would you know if the timer does not reach 0?

Comment: @Keppil when the same button that activates doSomething() and the timer is pressed on the second click of that button

Comment: You probably need to restructure your code to achieve that. From the code snippet, the timer should not repeat itself, except it is restarted in `doSomething()`. You also probably want to store a reference to it anywhere, when you need to cancel it on a second press to the button.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is good to know what doSomething() does. Moreover you may obtain the 10x execution using the onTick instead of onFinish. It really depends on what do you want to achieve. For example if doSomething is not reentrant using onTick would be not enough.